# Making a Custom Blazor component

Tags: .net-core, components, blazor, webassembly, blazor-webassembly

I am starting with some Blazor fun,
and one of the first things I am trying is to wrap my menu items to custom compoenents to make the navigation more readable.

I try something along the line:

File: Components\MenuItem.razor

```cshtml-razor
<AuthorizeView Roles="@Roles">
    <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="@Link">
            <span class="oi oi-task" aria-hidden="true"></span> @Text
        </NavLink>
    </li>
</AuthorizeView>
@code {
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Roles { get; set; }
}
```

But if I use the component instead of identical content in the navigation, nothing is loaded when i run the application.

in my navmenu, adding the following

```cshtml-razor
<VM.Web.Components.MenuItem Text="Approve user requests" Link="/users/pending-approval" Roles="ADMIN, CREW" />
```

stops the page from loading (I don't see any errors)
but the following directly in the navmenu works

```cshtml-razor
<AuthorizeView Roles="ADMIN, CREW">
    <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/users/pending-approval">
            <span class="oi oi-task" aria-hidden="true"></span> Approve user requests
        </NavLink>
    </li>
</AuthorizeView>
```

**Update**,
The issue was that I was missing the [Parameter] decoration, after that it worked

The final Component code looks like this

```cshtml-razor
<AuthorizeView Roles="@Roles">
    <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="@Link">
            <span class="@SpanClasses" aria-hidden="true"></span> @Text
        </NavLink>
    </li>
</AuthorizeView>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Link { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Roles { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string SpanClasses { get; set; }
}
```

For reference, The authentication module was implemented by another programmer and works :), it is configured like this

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.Bind("oidc", options.ProviderOptions);
        options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "role";
        options.AuthenticationPaths.LogInFailedPath = "/";
        options.AuthenticationPaths.LogOutSucceededPath = "/";
        options.AuthenticationPaths.LogOutCallbackPath = "/authentication/logout-callback";
    })
    .AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<ArrayClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteUserAccount>>();

AuthorityConnection = builder.Configuration.GetSection("oidc:Authority").Value;
```

Comment: Don't your public properties need a `[Parameter]` annotation?

Comment: That was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> directly in the navmenu works
>
> `<AuthorizeView Roles="ADMIN, CREW">`

Tells me your roles are being passed to WebAssembly

I found this useful when passing menu items as data. I needed to cater for unauthorized, authorized and I added roles.

The Claims factory that Enet has provided is also needed if any of the users have more than one role as they arrive in comma separated format.

`OptionalRolesAuthorizeView.razor`

```
@if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Roles) && RequireAuthentication == false)
{
    @ChildContent
}
else
{
    <AuthorizeView Roles="@Roles">
        @ChildContent
    </AuthorizeView>
}
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public bool RequireAuthentication { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Roles { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

`MenuItemView.razor`

```
<OptionalRolesAuthorizeView RequireAuthentication="@Model.RequireAuthentication" Roles="@Model.Roles">
    <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="@Model.Href" Match="@Model.Match">
            <span class="@Model.IconClass" aria-hidden="true"></span> @Model.Label
        </NavLink>
    </li>
</OptionalRolesAuthorizeView>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public MenuItem Model { get; set; }
}
```

`MenuItem.cs`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing;
public class MenuItem
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Href { get; set; }
    public string IconClass { get; set; }
    public bool RequireAuthentication { get; set; }
    public NavLinkMatch Match { get; set; }
    public string Roles { get; set; }
}
```

You should also look at [policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: thank you, I should look into using that aspNetCore MenuItem!